# Ayuda con dompdf y asignacion de variables

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdf, dom

Este el el codigo que llama el pdf

```
 <a href="pdf.php" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file">Descargar-PDF</i></a>
```

y este es el pdf.php

```html
<?php
require_once'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
// Reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// Instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
// Load HTML content
$dompdf->loadHtml('  <table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="1"; width="520"> 

        <tr>
            <td width="100"  rowspan="4">
                <p>
                    <img
                        width="100"
                        height="10"
                        src="file:///C:/Users/ASESOR~1/AppData/Local/Temp/msohtmlclip1/09/clip_image002.png"
                    />
                    <strong></strong>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td  height="18">
                <p align="center">
                 <font size=1>   PROCESO DE GESTIÓN DE RECURSOS</font>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td  height="18">
                <p align="center">
                   <font size=1> CÓDIGO
                </p>
            </td>
            <td  colspan="3"  height="10">
                <p align="center">
                  <font size=1>  FSW-100
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  height="18">
                <p align="center">
                   <font size=1> <strong>DEPARTAMENTO DE LAS TIC</strong>
                    <strong></strong>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td  rowspan="2"  height="10">
                <p align="center">
                   <font size=1> VERSIÓN 1
                </p>
            </td>
            <td  colspan="3" rowspan="2"  height="10">
                <p align="center">
                  <font size=1>  01-12-17
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  height="18">
                <p align="center">
                 <font size=1>   Tecnologías de la información y las comunicaciones
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  height="18">
                <p  align="center" >
                 <font size=2>   <strong>Acta de Entrega</strong></font>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td  height="18">
                <p align="center">
                <font size=1>    PAGINA
                </p>
            </td>
            <td  height="10">
                <p align="center">
                <font size=1>    1
                </p>
            </td>
            <td  height="18">
                <p align="center">
                <font size=1>    DE
                </p>
            </td>
            <td  height="18">
                <p align="center">
                  <font size=1>  2
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>   <font size=2> <table style="border-collapse: collapse; text-align: justify; margin-left: 4.8pt; margin-right: 4.8pt;" width="115">
<tbody>
<tr style="page-break-inside: avoid; height: 7.0pt;">
<td style="width: 519.25pt; border: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 7.0pt;" colspan="2" width="692">
<p><strong>Nombre del Usuario: </strong>MAYERLY ANGULO CORDOBA</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 7.4pt;">
<td style="width: 259.65pt; border: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 7.4pt;" width="346">
<p><strong>N&uacute;mero de Orden de Servicio:</strong> L070&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td style="width: 259.55pt; border: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 7.4pt;" width="346">
<p><strong>Tel&eacute;fono:</strong> &nbsp;3232021532</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 6.4pt;">
<td style="width: 519.25pt; border: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 6.4pt;" colspan="2" width="692">
<p><strong>No. De Cedula:</strong> 1010212772 de Bogot&aacute;</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</font>

<p  style="margin-top: 20px; line-height: normal;"><font size=2><strong>Herramientas</strong>: Se realiza entrega de computador port&aacute;til marca <strong>HP</strong> serie <strong>Pro desk 600 g1 sff</strong>, con n&uacute;mero de serial &nbsp;<strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;MXL4070KQW</strong>, con las siguientes caracter&iacute;sticas de hardware: procesador Intel core i5 6200u gen 6, memoria ram ddr 3 de 8 gb, disco duro de 500 gb de almacenamiento, pantalla antirreflejo de 21, color de equipo negro, con mouse de serial 674315-001 y teclado con serial 672646-163. se encuentra en un estado de <strong>usado</strong>.</p>

<p  style="margin-top: 20px; line-height: normal;"><font size=2><strong>Servicios:</strong> precargado con los siguiente software&acute;s: Windows 7 profesional, office 2016 home &amp; business, winrar, vlc, Skype, adobe reader, adatec para pc, Firefox, Chrome, plugins de navegaci&oacute;n, configuraciones, impresoras locales de oficinas swisslub, correo corporativo en pc y dispositivo m&oacute;vil, redes wifi y LAN.</p>

<p  style="margin-top: 20px; line-height: normal;"><font size=2>Usted como usuario asume la completa y total responsabilidad en caso de da&ntilde;o, perdida y deterioro del equipo entregado, fuera del deterioro normal con buen uso del equipo. <span style="color: black;">Este</span><span style="color: black; letter-spacing: 0pt;"> equipo es una estaci&oacute;n de trabajo que SWISSLUB S.A.S. est&aacute; poniendo a su disposici&oacute;n para uso dentro de sus oficinas; en caso31 de requerir trasladarlo quedar&aacute; bajo su riesgo y responsabilidad; esto quiere decir que, si el equipo sufre alg&uacute;n da&ntilde;o o perdida, usted deber&aacute; pagar el reemplazo del equipo, inmediatamente. Por lo cual, con su firma, a que los eventos detallados anteriormente, el valor del equipo le sea, descontado de n&oacute;mina o en caso de retiro de su liquidaci&oacute;n definitiva. Asimismo, el costo de reparaci&oacute;n o cambio de elemento da&ntilde;ado o perdido, siempre y cuando este da&ntilde;o no provenga del desgaste natural del equipo.</span></p>

<p style="margin-top: 20px; line-height: normal;"><font size=2> <span style="color: black; letter-spacing: 0pt;">La estaci&oacute;n de trabajo, solo funcionar&aacute; y deber&aacute; funcionar exclusivamente en el desarrollo de las actividades inherentes a su cargo. La informaci&oacute;n que se genere en el desarrollo de sus actividades como funcionario de la compa&ntilde;&iacute;a, estar&aacute;n alojadas en el equipo c&oacute;mputo perteneciente a <strong>SWISSLUB S.A.S.</strong>, prohibi&eacute;ndose su copiado y/o distribuci&oacute;n de las mismas a otros medios de almacenamiento, comunicaci&oacute;n a personas y segregaci&oacute;n de esta informaci&oacute;n; acorde a lo estipulado en la cl&aacute;usula segunda numeral dieciocho de sus obligaciones contractuales suscritas en su contrato de trabajo y reglamento interno de trabajo, articulo 45 numeral 1. De ninguna manera el equipo ser&aacute; utilizado para trabajo personal, almacenamiento de informaci&oacute;n personal y/o desarrollo recreativo; esta rotundamente prohibido la instalaci&oacute;n de software adicional sin autorizaci&oacute;n del Departamento de las TIC &ldquo;tecnolog&iacute;as de la informaci&oacute;n y la comunicaci&oacute;n&rdquo;; acorde a lo estipulado en la cl&aacute;usula segunda numeral diecisiete de sus obligaciones contractuales suscritas en su contrato de trabajo y reglamento interno de trabajo, articulo 45 numeral 9.</span></p>

<p  style="margin-top: 20px; line-height: normal;"><font size=2><span style="color: black; letter-spacing: 0pt;">Adicionalmente est&aacute; prohibido subir o bajar de Internet, m&uacute;sica y otros archivos ajenos al trabajo. Si el equipo muestra da&ntilde;o o mal funcionamiento por causa de archivos mal intencionados, y se encuentra m&uacute;sica o archivos ajenos al trabajo de la compa&ntilde;&iacute;a, los costos por reparaci&oacute;n y mantenimiento reinstalaci&oacute;n del sistema operativo y de los dem&aacute;s programas estar&aacute;n a su cargo.</span></p>

<p style="margin-top: 20px; text-align: justify;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt;">Observaciones: </span></p>

<table style="border-collapse: collapse; margin-left: 4.8pt; margin-right: 4.8pt;" width="525">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 6.2pt;">
<td style="width: 119.25pt; border: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 6.2pt;" width="192">
<p style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; line-height: normal;">&nbsp;</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 6.2pt;">
<td style="width: 100.25pt; border: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 6.2pt;" width="192">
<p style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; line-height: normal;">&nbsp;</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</font>
   ');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper( 'A4', 'portrait');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();

?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero qe quede asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En la parte de la tabla que se te sale prueba simplemente mermando el tamaño de la letra, está gigante, y quíta todos los width que agregaste a los td deja que se ajusten solos

Comment: cuando dijo que iba a venir a bogota jajajajajaja

Comment: Te funcionó esa parte? jajajaja

Comment: si XD otra cosa para modificar la altura toca celda por celda cierto porque igual me queda muy alto para la pagina

Comment: Inténta celda por celda a ver que pasa, en cuanto a lo de la información dinámica, edita tu pregunta y muestra como estás generando el pdf, estas llamando una url ? si es así puedes enviar todos los parámetros que necesitas por método GET y recibirlos en el archivo pdf con $_GET

Comment: ok un momento pruebo lo de las celdas

Comment: si pero solo se encogio hasta un punto

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67795/discussion-between-kevin-salazar-and-camilo-vasquez).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te dije en uno de los comentarios, la solución a la tabla que se te sale de la margen de la hoja es colocar los tamaño de textos más pequeños y quitar todos los width que agregaste a los td, esto para que ellos tengan la libertad de adaptarse.

Para enviar los datos que necesitas sean dinámicos podrías enviarlos por método GET de la siguiente forma:

```
 <a href="pdf.php?cedula=<?= $cedula ?>&nombre=<?= $nombre ?>" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file">Descargar-PDF</i></a>
```

Así sucesivamente puedes ir agregando los datos que necesitas a la url y en el archivo pdf.php los recibes de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php
require_once'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
// Reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// Instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();

$cedula = $_GET['cedula'];
$nombre= $_GET['nombre'];
```

Y ya luego solo los imprimes en el body de tu pdf

```
 '<p><strong>Nombre del Usuario: </strong>'. $nombre .'</p>'
```

**EXPLICACIÓN REQUERIDA**

Con el signo de interrogación (?) después de `pdf.php` estás indicando que vas a enviar variables utilizando el método get, y con el signo (&) estás separando una variable de otra.

Comment: no hay conflicto con el dompdf al pegar los datos deacuerdo a su sitio ok ya no jajjajaj no habia visto el resto XD gracias

Comment: Para nada, es un archivo php normal por lo cual puedes enviar variables por método get sin ningún problema, en lo que tienes que poner cuidado es a la hora de concatenar las variables (como el ejemplo que te mostré de un <p>) por que si cometes un error en una comilla dañas todo el código

Comment: ok np gracias por la ayuda

Comment: una pregunta esta linea de codigo porque ese signo de interrogacion <a href="pdf.phpESTE SIGNO"?"cedula=<?= $cedula ?>&nombre=<?= $nombre ?>"

Comment: Te coloqué la explicación en la respuesta.

Comment: ahh vale gracias